# copied files of a working project give errors

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jar

I copied some files of a working project into a different project on another computer, everything looks ok but an external jar cannot be resolved. I added jar file as I did on my first project. I tried everytihng (clear project, refresh etc...). It is a google app engine project. I added jar file into WEB-INF/lib. The jar is there but as I said project acts like it isn't there. What should I do?

P.S. I'm using Eclipse Juno.

SOLUTION !:

Hi again, I solved my problem. I first copied jar file into WEB-INF/lib and then I added jar file from Properties/Java Build Path/Add External Jar and problem was fixed.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to your own question, and validate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Hi again, I solved my problem. I first copied jar file into WEB-INF/lib and then I added jar file from Properties/Java Build Path/Add External Jar and problem was fixed.